# Find an img and change its visibility

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

When a true or false radio button is selected in  a table row, I want to display a particular image based on which radio was clicked. I've done some alerts here and am finding that I'm not even identifying the image, let alone changing it's visibility.

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr>
<td>This is a bit answer</td>
<td>
      <label>
          <input checked="checked" data-StudentScore="ScoreBit" id="StudentScores_0__ScoreBit" type="radio" value="" />
          Not answered
      </label>
      <label>
          <input data-StudentScore="ScoreBit" id="StudentScores_0__ScoreBit" type="radio" value="False" />
          False
      </label>
      <label>
          <input data-StudentScore="ScoreBit" id="StudentScores_0__ScoreBit" type="radio" value="True" />
          True
      </label>
</td>
<td class="met-image">
    <img class="Img-Met" style="visibility:visible" alt="Met" src="/Images/tick_circle.png" />
</td>
<td class ="not-met-image">
    <img class="Img-NotMet" style="visibility:hidden" alt="Not Met" src="/Images/minus_red_button.png" />
</td>
```

And here is the part of my script that isn't working (I've removed the 'If this or that button was clicked', as that isn't part of my issue).:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find("td.met-image").find('img[alt="Met"]').attr('style', "visibility':'hidden'");
    $(this).closest('tr').find("td.not-met-image").find('img[alt="Not Met"]').attr('style', "visibility':'visible'");
  });
});
```

Could someone please help me find the images that are in the same row as the clicked radio button, and change their visibility? FYI: this is in an MVC4 View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.css()` instead of `.attr()`. Actually `.css()` is made for setting css style properties. Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to know more about it.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find("td.met-image").find('img[alt="Met"]').css('visibility','hidden');
    $(this).closest('tr').find("td.not-met-image").find('img[alt="Not Met"]').css('visibility','visible');
 });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/AL3wM/1/)

Comment: Thank you everyone, and for the reminder to use fiddle as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need `css()` instead of `attr()` to change `visiblility`

```
$(this).closest('tr').find("td.met-image").find('img[alt="Met"]').css("visibility':'hidden'");
```

Your code would be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find("td.met-image").find('img[alt="Met"]').css("visibility':'hidden'");
    $(this).closest('tr').find("td.not-met-image").find('img[alt="Not Met"]').css( "visibility':'visible'");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use direclty with `css()`.

```
  $(this).closest('tr').find("td.met-image").find('img[alt="Met"]').css('visibility', 'hidden');

                                                                    ^^ change here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find("td.met-image").find('img[alt="Met"]').attr('style', "visibility:hidden");
$(this).closest('tr').find("td.not-met-image").find('img[alt="Not Met"]').attr('style', "visibility:visible");
```

OR

```
$(this).closest('tr').find("td.met-image").find('img[alt="Met"]').css("visibility","hidden");
$(this).closest('tr').find("td.not-met-image").find('img[alt="Not Met"]').css("visibility","visible");
```

NOTE:

You have not added `name` attribute to radio button.

HTML:

```
<input checked="checked" data-StudentScore="ScoreBit" id="StudentScores_0__ScoreBit" name="answer" type="radio" value="" />
<input data-StudentScore="ScoreBit" id="StudentScores_0__ScoreBit" name="answer" type="radio" value="False" />
<input data-StudentScore="ScoreBit" id="StudentScores_0__ScoreBit" name="answer" type="radio" value="True" />
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6B923/)